# unbale to click on button on real device(mobile)

Tags: appium, appium-android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fudGc.png)@Test
String text= driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log in")).getText();

```
    MobileElement SignuP = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.Button"));
    SignuP.click();
```

Comment: Did you initialize AppiumDriver? can you add the appium server log?

Comment: can you share more information

Comment: you can use different locator rather than class name share some more information about element locator

Answer (score 1):

By index has work when there is no common id,classpath or accessiblity id

```
List<WebElement>list =driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.Button"));
        list.get(0).click();                
        //or we can use xpath
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='Log in']")).click();
```